# Drawing multiple views inside an Activity

Tags: android, view, draw

I'm new to Android programming and I have some basic issues concerning drawing.

I have an activity displaying a textview through the .xml file, which looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to display several rectangles inside my Activity. To do so, I created a new class that extends View. I instantiated the class and managed to display my rectangle inside my Activity (maybe I should use the word layout here, I'm not sure...).

The class I created:

```
public class DrawRectangle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int x,y;
    int length,width;

    public DrawRectangle(Context context,int _x,int _y, int _length, int _width){
        super(context);
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        length = _length;
        width = _width;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+length, y+length, paint);
    }
}
```

And the function inside the activity that create the instance of DrawRectangle class:

```
public void drawRectangle(){

    DrawRectangle rectangle = new DrawRectangle(this,100,100,50,50);
    // rectangle.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    setContentView(rectangle);
}
```

This is what happened:

- The rectangle has been drawn correctly
- We can't see the textview anymore

I tried to create another instance of the DrawRectangle class and only one can be seen (the last one to be set on screen). I supposed the problem came from the fact that the view took all the place and was placed in front of everything. So I tried to change the background color to transparent using the line:

```
rectangle.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

or

```
rectangle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000");
```

There wasn't any error, but the other rectangle or text view couldn't be seen.

What can I do? I suspect a miss-comprehension concerning all this.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setContentView` you have to pass the xml layout of your activity ( containing the TextView ).
Later you could add others Views to this layout. For example:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("Added tv");
layout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Thx for answering. How can I get/know my layout ID ? Concerning the findViewByID(R.id.your_layout_id).

Comment: it's the name of layout xml file.

Comment: My layout didn't have any ID, so that is why I was a bit lost. Now it's working ! Thx !